# I am trying to call InvokeMethod for any method which arguments accept some Ref parameters it is giving exceptions

Tags: c#, com, interop

I want to know how to pass arguments to a method which are ref / out when the method is called using InvokeMember.

I am trying to call InvokeMethod for any method which arguments accept some Ref parameters it is giving exceptions.

Comment: how is the method declared & how you are calling it ?

Answer (score 1):

Works with ref and out modifiers.

```
public class Example {
  public static void Foo(ref string name) {
    name = "foo";
  }
  public static void Test() {
    var p = new object[1];
    var info = typeof(Example).GetMethod("Foo");
    info.Invoke(null, p);
    var returned = (string)(p[0]);  // will be "foo"
  }
}
```